# adding string literal to static_assert

Tags: c++, static-assert

Is there a way to combine what's going to be output by static_assert? What I mean is this:

```
template<class T>
struct X
{
static_assert(std::is_signed<T>::value, "Type " + T + " must be signed.");//this doesn't work
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the basis that this does not compile

```
int main()
{
   const char c[2] = "1";
   static_assert(1==1, c)
}
```

nor this

```
int main()
{
   const char* c = "1";
   static_assert(1==1, c)
}
```

Both with errors `error: expected a string literal` then I would have to conclude that it is not possible.

"A string literal consists of zero or more characters from the source character set surrounded by double quotation marks ("). A string literal represents a sequence of characters that, taken together, form a null-terminated string." - [C++ String Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You might want to consider using [`Boost::StaticAssert`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) as this might give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but it gives meaningful failure messages, so will output the type in the failure string of the assert.

Comment: IMO, boost static_assert does not give any more meaningful messages. Both point you to the line but one says something like: "In instantiation of 'X<unsigned int>' ... error: static assertion failed: "Type must be signed.". And the other says something like: "... error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'"

Comment: @UncleBens agreed. Boost isn't the way to go (in this case).

Comment: @There You could try using BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG. True the 'message' is just a type that shows up in the error, But I find it more usable than almost any other static assert mechanism out there.